# NSScrollView doesn't call drawRect for documentView

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsscrollview

I have NSScrollView with drawable content. 
It works fine with scrolling until I press Cmd+Tab or hide window in any other way. 
When I open window with scrollView second time it doesn't redraw content on scrolling. 
so drawRect function for documentView doesn't work anymore.

setting content view (I need to redraw it on scrolling because self.documentView is much wider than window's width)
[self.documentScroll setDocumentView:self.documentView];

in NSClipView

-(void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {

```
[self setCopiesOnScroll: NO];
[super drawRect:dirtyRect];

NSArray* ar = self.subviews;
NSView* docView = ar.firstObject;
BOOL b = docView.needsDisplay;
```

}

docView.needsDisplay is always NO after window was hidden and shown second time. On application's launch it's always YES and drawRect method calls for documentView on every scrolling event

Comment: Why do you override `drawRect` of the clipview? `drawRect` should be used for drawing and nothing else.

Comment: problem is solved. Thank you! I deleted drawRect from my clipView and now it works